# How to add body tags dynamically ih php

Tags: php

I have lots of files on server which i need to modify by php script. I want to add html   tags before and after the files content.

Comment: So what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: please provide any code?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Basically, you can do this:

```
$file_name = 'something';
$old_content = file_get_contents($file_name);

$html_before = '<html>... something before the old content';
$html_after = '</html>... something after the old content';

$result = $html_before . $old_content . $html_after;

file_put_contents($file_name, $result); // overwrite the original file. make sure you have backup for that.
```

If you want to do this for all files inside a directory, you can try:

```
$dir_path = '/path/to/your/dir';

$dir = dir($dir_path);
if ($dir !== false) {
    while (($item = $dir->read()) !== false) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue; // skip . and ..
        $path = $dir->path . '/' . $item;
        if (is_dir($path)) continue; // skip directory

        $old_content = file_get_contents($path);

        $html_before = '<html>... something before the old content';
        $html_after = '</html>... something after the old content';

        $result = $html_before . $old_content . $html_after;

        file_put_contents($path, $result); // overwrite the original file!
    }
    $dir->close();
}
```